# Always know what test statistic to use

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Is there a systematic way to understand what test statistic to use ahead of a random variable $X$ with population of $n$ and parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ that may or may not be unknown?

For example, if $n < 30$, $\mu, \sigma^2$ are unknowns, I should use $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathcal{X}^2$; but if $n > 30$ I should use the approximation for $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{s/\sqrt{n}} \sim normal(0,1)$, etc.

I never know what test to use from $t-student$, $normal$ and $\mathcal{X}^2$ for these parameters. Is there a way to always know?

Comment: With modern statistical packages, you can use the $t$-statistics in all cases with an unknown mean and variance. The traditional $>30$ rule of thumb was because printed statistical tables had limited space and a normal approximation was then usually close enough.

Comment: [Hope this helps.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178854/a-b-tests-z-test-vs-t-test-vs-chi-square-vs-fisher-exact-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the above mentioned link, here's another link that I think you'll find helpful: [The Link](https://www.journeywithasr.com/2021/02/tests-of-significance-t-test-z-test-chi-square-test-and-f-test.html#:%7E:text=t%20Test%3A%20Hypothesis%20testing%20for,the%20differences%20between%20population%20means.)

It's relevant summary is as follows:

1. When n > 30, it will follow **normal distribution** . Z test is carried out, when sample size is > 30.
2. With small samples and when the degrees of freedom less than 30, the variates
   are not normally distributed. Hence we make use of the **‘t’ distribution** and ‘t’ test of significance.
3. *When sample size is large ($n>50$), samples are independent and there are a minimum of five observations expected in each group or combination of groups.* $\bf\chi^2$ **test** can be used. This test is used in the case when observed frequencies are to be tested for their fit with expected or theoretical frequencies or to test whether two factors of classification of a set of individuals presented in the form of two- way table are independent or not.

**Note**: Italicized part is not mentioned in the link.

---

#### ***Addendum:***

For $\chi^2$ test,

1. If the sample size, $n<50$, it's recommended to use *Fisher’s exact test*.
2. If expected frequency, $e<5$ then *pooling techniques* is used.

Comment: Can I use $\mathcal{X}^2$ when sample size is $\leq 30$ and variance is unknown?
So general rule is that for $n \geq 30$ I can always approximate to a normal distribution through $Z-score$, right? Even for test hypothesis?

Comment: @ludicrous I have edited my answer, please check. Also, whether variance is known or not doesn't matter, main thing, in your case, is the sample size, which I have addressed above. Finally, when n>=30, yes normal you may use, but it's for quantitative data. On the other hand, we use Chi-square test only when the data is nominal (categorical).